# How to get the list of timezones supported by PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I found this documentation here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html

However, it does not really mention how to get a list of all the supported timezones. How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may try *selecting* from the view `pg_timezone_names`, as the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/view-pg-timezone-names.html) says:

> The view pg_timezone_names provides a list of time zone names that are recognized by SET TIMEZONE, along with their associated abbreviations, UTC offsets, and daylight-savings status.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    name,
    abbrev,
    utc_offset,
    is_dst
FROM pg_timezone_names;
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Tim was excellent.
For whatever reason my Postgres DB also contained a bunch of fluff with the prefix "posix/" and I also needed these in alphabetical order to use on a website, so I did this:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    abbrev,
    utc_offset,
    is_dst
FROM pg_timezone_names 
WHERE name !~ 'posix' 
ORDER BY name asc;
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran this query and [pasted the results here](https://bill.harding.blog/2020/03/21/list-of-postgres-11-time-zones/) if anybody wants to save the time of running it themselves.

Comment: Just note, that  the list may be different depending on the postgres-version.

Answer (score 2):

The query returns time zones grouped by offset so that it will be easier to chose:

```
SELECT utc_offset, is_dst,
       ltrim(
               trim(string_agg(distinct (CASE WHEN abbrev NOT LIKE '+%' AND abbrev NOT LIKE '-%' AND abbrev != name THEN abbrev ELSE '' END), ' ')) ||
               ' ' || string_agg(name, ', ' ORDER BY name)
       )
FROM pg_timezone_names
WHERE name NOT LIKE 'posix/%'
  AND name NOT LIKE 'Etc/%'
  AND name NOT IN ('HST', 'Factory', 'GMT', 'GMT+0', 'GMT-0', 'GMT0', 'localtime', 'UCT', 'Universal', 'UTC', 'PST8PDT', 'ROK', 'W-SU', 'MST', 'CST6CDT')
GROUP BY utc_offset, is_dst
ORDER BY utc_offset, is_dst
```

And result is:

```
-11,false,"SST Pacific/Midway, Pacific/Niue, Pacific/Pago_Pago, Pacific/Samoa, US/Samoa"
-10,false,"HST Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Johnston, Pacific/Rarotonga, Pacific/Tahiti, US/Hawaii"
-9:30,false,Pacific/Marquesas
-9,false,Pacific/Gambier
-9,true,"HDT America/Adak, America/Atka, US/Aleutian"
-8,false,Pacific/Pitcairn
-8,true,"AKDT America/Anchorage, America/Juneau, America/Metlakatla, America/Nome, America/Sitka, America/Yakutat, US/Alaska"
-7,false,"MST America/Creston, America/Dawson, America/Dawson_Creek, America/Fort_Nelson, America/Hermosillo, America/Phoenix, America/Whitehorse, Canada/Yukon, US/Arizona"
-7,true,"PDT America/Ensenada, America/Los_Angeles, America/Santa_Isabel, America/Tijuana, America/Vancouver, Canada/Pacific, Mexico/BajaNorte, US/Pacific"
-6,false,"CST America/Belize, America/Costa_Rica, America/El_Salvador, America/Guatemala, America/Managua, America/Regina, America/Swift_Current, America/Tegucigalpa, Canada/Saskatchewan, Chile/EasterIsland, Pacific/Easter, Pacific/Galapagos"
-6,true,"MDT America/Boise, America/Cambridge_Bay, America/Chihuahua, America/Denver, America/Edmonton, America/Inuvik, America/Mazatlan, America/Ojinaga, America/Shiprock, America/Yellowknife, Canada/Mountain, Mexico/BajaSur, MST7MDT, Navajo, US/Mountain"
-5,false,"EST America/Atikokan, America/Bogota, America/Cancun, America/Cayman, America/Coral_Harbour, America/Eirunepe, America/Guayaquil, America/Jamaica, America/Lima, America/Panama, America/Porto_Acre, America/Rio_Branco, Brazil/Acre, EST, Jamaica"
-5,true,"CDT America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Chicago, America/Indiana/Knox, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Knox_IN, America/Matamoros, America/Menominee, America/Merida, America/Mexico_City, America/Monterrey, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, America/Rainy_River, America/Rankin_Inlet, America/Resolute, America/Winnipeg, Canada/Central, Mexico/General, US/Central, US/Indiana-Starke"
-4,false,"AST America/Anguilla, America/Antigua, America/Aruba, America/Asuncion, America/Barbados, America/Blanc-Sablon, America/Boa_Vista, America/Campo_Grande, America/Caracas, America/Cuiaba, America/Curacao, America/Dominica, America/Grenada, America/Guadeloupe, America/Guyana, America/Kralendijk, America/La_Paz, America/Lower_Princes, America/Manaus, America/Marigot, America/Martinique, America/Montserrat, America/Port_of_Spain, America/Porto_Velho, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Santiago, America/Santo_Domingo, America/St_Barthelemy, America/St_Kitts, America/St_Lucia, America/St_Thomas, America/St_Vincent, America/Tortola, America/Virgin, Brazil/West, Chile/Continental"
-4,true,"CDT EDT America/Detroit, America/Fort_Wayne, America/Grand_Turk, America/Havana, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, America/Indiana/Marengo, America/Indiana/Petersburg, America/Indianapolis, America/Indiana/Vevay, America/Indiana/Vincennes, America/Indiana/Winamac, America/Iqaluit, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Kentucky/Monticello, America/Louisville, America/Montreal, America/Nassau, America/New_York, America/Nipigon, America/Pangnirtung, America/Port-au-Prince, America/Thunder_Bay, America/Toronto, Canada/Eastern, Cuba, EST5EDT, posixrules, US/Eastern, US/East-Indiana, US/Michigan"
-3,false,"America/Araguaina, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, America/Argentina/Catamarca, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Argentina/Cordoba, America/Argentina/Jujuy, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, America/Argentina/Mendoza, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, America/Argentina/Salta, America/Argentina/San_Juan, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Argentina/Tucuman, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, America/Bahia, America/Belem, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Catamarca, America/Cayenne, America/Cordoba, America/Fortaleza, America/Jujuy, America/Maceio, America/Mendoza, America/Montevideo, America/Paramaribo, America/Punta_Arenas, America/Recife, America/Rosario, America/Santarem, America/Sao_Paulo, Antarctica/Palmer, Antarctica/Rothera, Atlantic/Stanley, Brazil/East"
-3,true,"ADT America/Glace_Bay, America/Goose_Bay, America/Halifax, America/Moncton, America/Thule, Atlantic/Bermuda, Canada/Atlantic"
-2:30,true,"NDT America/St_Johns, Canada/Newfoundland"
-2,false,"America/Noronha, Atlantic/South_Georgia, Brazil/DeNoronha"
-2,true,"America/Godthab, America/Miquelon, America/Nuuk"
-1,false,Atlantic/Cape_Verde
+0,false,"GMT UTC Africa/Abidjan, Africa/Accra, Africa/Bamako, Africa/Banjul, Africa/Bissau, Africa/Conakry, Africa/Dakar, Africa/Freetown, Africa/Lome, Africa/Monrovia, Africa/Nouakchott, Africa/Ouagadougou, Africa/Sao_Tome, Africa/Timbuktu, America/Danmarkshavn, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Atlantic/St_Helena, Greenwich, Iceland, Zulu"
+0,true,"America/Scoresbysund, Atlantic/Azores"
+1,false,"CET IST WAT Africa/Algiers, Africa/Bangui, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Casablanca, Africa/Douala, Africa/El_Aaiun, Africa/Kinshasa, Africa/Lagos, Africa/Libreville, Africa/Luanda, Africa/Malabo, Africa/Ndjamena, Africa/Niamey, Africa/Porto-Novo, Africa/Tunis, Eire, Europe/Dublin"
+1,true,"BST WEST Atlantic/Canary, Atlantic/Faeroe, Atlantic/Faroe, Atlantic/Madeira, Europe/Belfast, Europe/Guernsey, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Europe/Jersey, Europe/Lisbon, Europe/London, GB, GB-Eire, Portugal, WET"
+2,false,"CAT EET SAST Africa/Blantyre, Africa/Bujumbura, Africa/Cairo, Africa/Gaborone, Africa/Harare, Africa/Johannesburg, Africa/Juba, Africa/Khartoum, Africa/Kigali, Africa/Lubumbashi, Africa/Lusaka, Africa/Maputo, Africa/Maseru, Africa/Mbabane, Africa/Tripoli, Africa/Windhoek, Egypt, Europe/Kaliningrad, Libya"
+2,true,"CEST MEST Africa/Ceuta, Antarctica/Troll, Arctic/Longyearbyen, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, CET, Europe/Amsterdam, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Belgrade, Europe/Berlin, Europe/Bratislava, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Busingen, Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Gibraltar, Europe/Ljubljana, Europe/Luxembourg, Europe/Madrid, Europe/Malta, Europe/Monaco, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Paris, Europe/Podgorica, Europe/Prague, Europe/Rome, Europe/San_Marino, Europe/Sarajevo, Europe/Skopje, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Tirane, Europe/Vaduz, Europe/Vatican, Europe/Vienna, Europe/Warsaw, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Zurich, MET, Poland"
+3,false,"EAT MSK Africa/Addis_Ababa, Africa/Asmara, Africa/Asmera, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Africa/Djibouti, Africa/Kampala, Africa/Mogadishu, Africa/Nairobi, Antarctica/Syowa, Asia/Aden, Asia/Baghdad, Asia/Bahrain, Asia/Istanbul, Asia/Kuwait, Asia/Qatar, Asia/Riyadh, Europe/Istanbul, Europe/Kirov, Europe/Minsk, Europe/Moscow, Europe/Simferopol, Europe/Volgograd, Indian/Antananarivo, Indian/Comoro, Indian/Mayotte, Turkey"
+3,true,"EEST IDT Asia/Amman, Asia/Beirut, Asia/Damascus, Asia/Famagusta, Asia/Gaza, Asia/Hebron, Asia/Jerusalem, Asia/Nicosia, Asia/Tel_Aviv, EET, Europe/Athens, Europe/Bucharest, Europe/Chisinau, Europe/Helsinki, Europe/Kiev, Europe/Mariehamn, Europe/Nicosia, Europe/Riga, Europe/Sofia, Europe/Tallinn, Europe/Tiraspol, Europe/Uzhgorod, Europe/Vilnius, Europe/Zaporozhye, Israel"
+4,false,"Asia/Baku, Asia/Dubai, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Tbilisi, Asia/Yerevan, Europe/Astrakhan, Europe/Samara, Europe/Saratov, Europe/Ulyanovsk, Indian/Mahe, Indian/Mauritius, Indian/Reunion"
+4:30,false,Asia/Kabul
+4:30,true,"Asia/Tehran, Iran"
+5,false,"PKT Antarctica/Mawson, Asia/Aqtau, Asia/Aqtobe, Asia/Ashgabat, Asia/Ashkhabad, Asia/Atyrau, Asia/Dushanbe, Asia/Karachi, Asia/Oral, Asia/Qyzylorda, Asia/Samarkand, Asia/Tashkent, Asia/Yekaterinburg, Indian/Kerguelen, Indian/Maldives"
+5:30,false,"IST Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Colombo, Asia/Kolkata"
+5:45,false,"Asia/Kathmandu, Asia/Katmandu"
+6,false,"Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Bishkek, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Dhaka, Asia/Kashgar, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Qostanay, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu, Asia/Urumqi, Indian/Chagos"
+6:30,false,"Asia/Rangoon, Asia/Yangon, Indian/Cocos"
+7,false,"WIB Antarctica/Davis, Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Barnaul, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Asia/Hovd, Asia/Jakarta, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Asia/Novokuznetsk, Asia/Novosibirsk, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Asia/Pontianak, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Tomsk, Asia/Vientiane, Indian/Christmas"
+8,false,"AWST CST HKT PST WITA Asia/Brunei, Asia/Choibalsan, Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Hong_Kong, Asia/Irkutsk, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Kuching, Asia/Macao, Asia/Macau, Asia/Makassar, Asia/Manila, Asia/Shanghai, Asia/Singapore, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Ulan_Bator, Australia/Perth, Australia/West, Hongkong, PRC, ROC, Singapore"
+8:45,false,Australia/Eucla
+9,false,"JST KST WIT Asia/Chita, Asia/Dili, Asia/Jayapura, Asia/Khandyga, Asia/Pyongyang, Asia/Seoul, Asia/Tokyo, Asia/Yakutsk, Japan, Pacific/Palau"
+9:30,false,"ACST Australia/Adelaide, Australia/Broken_Hill, Australia/Darwin, Australia/North, Australia/South, Australia/Yancowinna"
+10,false,"AEST ChST Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Antarctica/Macquarie, Asia/Ust-Nera, Asia/Vladivostok, Australia/ACT, Australia/Brisbane, Australia/Canberra, Australia/Currie, Australia/Hobart, Australia/Lindeman, Australia/Melbourne, Australia/NSW, Australia/Queensland, Australia/Sydney, Australia/Tasmania, Australia/Victoria, Pacific/Chuuk, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Port_Moresby, Pacific/Saipan, Pacific/Truk, Pacific/Yap"
+10:30,false,"Australia/LHI, Australia/Lord_Howe"
+11,false,"Antarctica/Casey, Asia/Magadan, Asia/Sakhalin, Asia/Srednekolymsk, Pacific/Bougainville, Pacific/Efate, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Pacific/Kosrae, Pacific/Norfolk, Pacific/Noumea, Pacific/Pohnpei, Pacific/Ponape"
+12,false,"NZST Antarctica/McMurdo, Antarctica/South_Pole, Asia/Anadyr, Asia/Kamchatka, Kwajalein, NZ, Pacific/Auckland, Pacific/Fiji, Pacific/Funafuti, Pacific/Kwajalein, Pacific/Majuro, Pacific/Nauru, Pacific/Tarawa, Pacific/Wake, Pacific/Wallis"
+12:45,false,"NZ-CHAT, Pacific/Chatham"
+13,false,"Pacific/Apia, Pacific/Enderbury, Pacific/Fakaofo, Pacific/Kanton, Pacific/Tongatapu"
+14,false,Pacific/Kiritimati
```

This is ready to use for a Time Zone selector. The DST i.e. a summer time items I show in a different color.

Answer (score 0):

## Non-Posix List

Version: `PostgreSQL 9.3.25`

Query:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    abbrev,
    utc_offset,
    is_dst
FROM pg_timezone_names 
WHERE name !~ 'posix' 
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2, 4
;
```

Here is the list:

```
'name','abbrev','utc_offset','is_dst'
'Etc/GMT+12','-12','-12:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+11','-11','-11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Midway','SST','-11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Niue','-11','-11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Pago_Pago','SST','-11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Samoa','SST','-11:00:00','false'
'US/Samoa','SST','-11:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+10','-10','-10:00:00','false'
'HST','HST','-10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Honolulu','HST','-10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Johnston','HST','-10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Rarotonga','-10','-10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Tahiti','-10','-10:00:00','false'
'US/Hawaii','HST','-10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Marquesas','-0930','-09:30:00','false'
'America/Adak','HDT','-09:00:00','true'
'America/Atka','HDT','-09:00:00','true'
'Etc/GMT+9','-09','-09:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Gambier','-09','-09:00:00','false'
'US/Aleutian','HDT','-09:00:00','true'
'America/Anchorage','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'America/Juneau','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'America/Metlakatla','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'America/Nome','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'America/Sitka','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'America/Yakutat','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'Etc/GMT+8','-08','-08:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Pitcairn','-08','-08:00:00','false'
'US/Alaska','AKDT','-08:00:00','true'
'America/Creston','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'America/Dawson','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'America/Dawson_Creek','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'America/Ensenada','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'America/Fort_Nelson','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'America/Hermosillo','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'America/Los_Angeles','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'America/Phoenix','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'America/Santa_Isabel','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'America/Tijuana','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'America/Vancouver','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'America/Whitehorse','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'Canada/Pacific','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'Canada/Yukon','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+7','-07','-07:00:00','false'
'MST','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'Mexico/BajaNorte','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'PST8PDT','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'US/Arizona','MST','-07:00:00','false'
'US/Pacific','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'US/Pacific-New','PDT','-07:00:00','true'
'America/Belize','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Boise','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Cambridge_Bay','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Chihuahua','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Costa_Rica','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Denver','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Edmonton','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/El_Salvador','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Guatemala','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Inuvik','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Managua','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Mazatlan','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Ojinaga','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Regina','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Shiprock','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Swift_Current','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Tegucigalpa','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'America/Yellowknife','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'Canada/Mountain','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'Canada/Saskatchewan','CST','-06:00:00','false'
'Chile/EasterIsland','-06','-06:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+6','-06','-06:00:00','false'
'MST7MDT','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'Mexico/BajaSur','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'Navajo','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'Pacific/Easter','-06','-06:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Galapagos','-06','-06:00:00','false'
'US/Mountain','MDT','-06:00:00','true'
'America/Atikokan','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Bahia_Banderas','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Bogota','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Cancun','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Cayman','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Chicago','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Coral_Harbour','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Eirunepe','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Guayaquil','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Indiana/Knox','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Tell_City','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Jamaica','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Knox_IN','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Lima','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Matamoros','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Menominee','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Merida','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Mexico_City','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Monterrey','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/North_Dakota/Beulah','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/North_Dakota/Center','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Panama','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Porto_Acre','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Rainy_River','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Rankin_Inlet','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Resolute','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Rio_Branco','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'America/Winnipeg','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'Brazil/Acre','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'CST6CDT','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'Canada/Central','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'EST','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+5','-05','-05:00:00','false'
'Jamaica','EST','-05:00:00','false'
'Mexico/General','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'US/Central','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'US/Indiana-Starke','CDT','-05:00:00','true'
'America/Anguilla','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Antigua','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Aruba','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Asuncion','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Barbados','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Blanc-Sablon','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Boa_Vista','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Campo_Grande','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Caracas','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Cuiaba','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Curacao','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Detroit','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Dominica','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Fort_Wayne','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Grand_Turk','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Grenada','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Guadeloupe','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Guyana','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Havana','CDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Indianapolis','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Marengo','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Petersburg','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Vevay','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Vincennes','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indiana/Winamac','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Indianapolis','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Iqaluit','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Kentucky/Louisville','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Kentucky/Monticello','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Kralendijk','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/La_Paz','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Louisville','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Lower_Princes','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Manaus','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Marigot','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Martinique','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Montreal','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Montserrat','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Nassau','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/New_York','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Nipigon','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Pangnirtung','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Port-au-Prince','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Port_of_Spain','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Porto_Velho','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Puerto_Rico','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Santiago','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Santo_Domingo','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/St_Barthelemy','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/St_Kitts','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/St_Lucia','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/St_Thomas','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/St_Vincent','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Thunder_Bay','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Toronto','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Tortola','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'America/Virgin','AST','-04:00:00','false'
'Brazil/West','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'Canada/Eastern','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'Chile/Continental','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'Cuba','CDT','-04:00:00','true'
'EST5EDT','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'Etc/GMT+4','-04','-04:00:00','false'
'US/East-Indiana','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'US/Eastern','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'US/Michigan','EDT','-04:00:00','true'
'America/Araguaina','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Catamarca','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Cordoba','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Jujuy','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/La_Rioja','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Mendoza','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Salta','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/San_Juan','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/San_Luis','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Tucuman','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Argentina/Ushuaia','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Bahia','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Belem','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Buenos_Aires','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Catamarca','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Cayenne','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Cordoba','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Fortaleza','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Glace_Bay','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'America/Goose_Bay','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'America/Halifax','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'America/Jujuy','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Maceio','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Mendoza','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Moncton','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'America/Montevideo','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Paramaribo','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Punta_Arenas','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Recife','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Rosario','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Santarem','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Sao_Paulo','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/Thule','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'Antarctica/Palmer','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'Antarctica/Rothera','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'Atlantic/Bermuda','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Stanley','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'Brazil/East','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'Canada/Atlantic','ADT','-03:00:00','true'
'Etc/GMT+3','-03','-03:00:00','false'
'America/St_Johns','NDT','-02:30:00','true'
'Canada/Newfoundland','NDT','-02:30:00','true'
'America/Godthab','-02','-02:00:00','true'
'America/Miquelon','-02','-02:00:00','true'
'America/Noronha','-02','-02:00:00','false'
'America/Nuuk','-02','-02:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/South_Georgia','-02','-02:00:00','false'
'Brazil/DeNoronha','-02','-02:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+2','-02','-02:00:00','false'
'Atlantic/Cape_Verde','-01','-01:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+1','-01','-01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Abidjan','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Accra','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Bamako','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Banjul','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Bissau','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Conakry','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Dakar','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Freetown','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Lome','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Monrovia','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Nouakchott','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Ouagadougou','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Sao_Tome','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Timbuktu','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'America/Danmarkshavn','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'America/Scoresbysund','+00','00:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Azores','+00','00:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Reykjavik','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Atlantic/St_Helena','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT+0','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-0','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT0','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/Greenwich','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/UCT','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/UTC','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/Universal','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'Etc/Zulu','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'GMT','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'GMT+0','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'GMT-0','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'GMT0','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Greenwich','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'Iceland','GMT','00:00:00','false'
'UCT','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'UTC','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'Universal','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'Zulu','UTC','00:00:00','false'
'Africa/Algiers','CET','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Bangui','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Brazzaville','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Casablanca','+01','01:00:00','true'
'Africa/Douala','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/El_Aaiun','+01','01:00:00','true'
'Africa/Kinshasa','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Lagos','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Libreville','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Luanda','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Malabo','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Ndjamena','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Niamey','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Porto-Novo','WAT','01:00:00','false'
'Africa/Tunis','CET','01:00:00','false'
'Atlantic/Canary','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Faeroe','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Faroe','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Madeira','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'Eire','IST','01:00:00','true'
'Etc/GMT-1','+01','01:00:00','false'
'Europe/Belfast','BST','01:00:00','true'
'Europe/Dublin','IST','01:00:00','true'
'Europe/Guernsey','BST','01:00:00','true'
'Europe/Isle_of_Man','BST','01:00:00','true'
'Europe/Jersey','BST','01:00:00','true'
'Europe/Lisbon','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'Europe/London','BST','01:00:00','true'
'GB','BST','01:00:00','true'
'GB-Eire','BST','01:00:00','true'
'Portugal','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'WET','WEST','01:00:00','true'
'Africa/Blantyre','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Bujumbura','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Cairo','EET','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Ceuta','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Africa/Gaborone','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Harare','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Johannesburg','SAST','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Khartoum','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Kigali','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Lubumbashi','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Lusaka','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Maputo','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Maseru','SAST','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Mbabane','SAST','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Tripoli','EET','02:00:00','false'
'Africa/Windhoek','CAT','02:00:00','false'
'Antarctica/Troll','+02','02:00:00','true'
'Arctic/Longyearbyen','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Atlantic/Jan_Mayen','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'CET','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Egypt','EET','02:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-2','+02','02:00:00','false'
'Europe/Amsterdam','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Andorra','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Belgrade','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Berlin','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Bratislava','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Brussels','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Budapest','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Busingen','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Copenhagen','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Gibraltar','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Kaliningrad','EET','02:00:00','false'
'Europe/Ljubljana','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Luxembourg','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Madrid','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Malta','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Monaco','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Oslo','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Paris','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Podgorica','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Prague','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Rome','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/San_Marino','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Sarajevo','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Skopje','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Stockholm','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Tirane','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Vaduz','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Vatican','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Vienna','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Warsaw','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Zagreb','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Europe/Zurich','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Libya','EET','02:00:00','false'
'MET','MEST','02:00:00','true'
'Poland','CEST','02:00:00','true'
'Africa/Addis_Ababa','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Asmara','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Asmera','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Djibouti','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Juba','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Kampala','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Mogadishu','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Africa/Nairobi','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Antarctica/Syowa','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Aden','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Amman','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Baghdad','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Bahrain','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Beirut','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Damascus','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Famagusta','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Gaza','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Hebron','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Istanbul','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Jerusalem','IDT','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Kuwait','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Nicosia','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Asia/Qatar','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Riyadh','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Tel_Aviv','IDT','03:00:00','true'
'EET','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Etc/GMT-3','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Europe/Athens','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Bucharest','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Chisinau','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Helsinki','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Istanbul','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Europe/Kiev','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Kirov','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Europe/Mariehamn','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Minsk','+03','03:00:00','false'
'Europe/Moscow','MSK','03:00:00','false'
'Europe/Nicosia','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Riga','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Simferopol','MSK','03:00:00','false'
'Europe/Sofia','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Tallinn','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Tiraspol','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Uzhgorod','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Vilnius','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Europe/Zaporozhye','EEST','03:00:00','true'
'Indian/Antananarivo','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Indian/Comoro','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Indian/Mayotte','EAT','03:00:00','false'
'Israel','IDT','03:00:00','true'
'Turkey','+03','03:00:00','false'
'W-SU','MSK','03:00:00','false'
'Asia/Baku','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Asia/Dubai','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Asia/Muscat','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Asia/Tbilisi','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Asia/Yerevan','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-4','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Europe/Astrakhan','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Europe/Samara','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Europe/Saratov','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Europe/Ulyanovsk','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Europe/Volgograd','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Indian/Mahe','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Indian/Mauritius','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Indian/Reunion','+04','04:00:00','false'
'Asia/Kabul','+0430','04:30:00','false'
'Asia/Tehran','+0430','04:30:00','true'
'Iran','+0430','04:30:00','true'
'Antarctica/Mawson','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Aqtau','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Aqtobe','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ashgabat','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ashkhabad','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Atyrau','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Dushanbe','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Karachi','PKT','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Oral','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Qyzylorda','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Samarkand','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Tashkent','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Yekaterinburg','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-5','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Indian/Kerguelen','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Indian/Maldives','+05','05:00:00','false'
'Asia/Calcutta','IST','05:30:00','false'
'Asia/Colombo','+0530','05:30:00','false'
'Asia/Kolkata','IST','05:30:00','false'
'Asia/Kathmandu','+0545','05:45:00','false'
'Asia/Katmandu','+0545','05:45:00','false'
'Antarctica/Vostok','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Almaty','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Bishkek','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Dacca','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Dhaka','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Kashgar','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Omsk','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Qostanay','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Thimbu','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Thimphu','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Urumqi','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-6','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Indian/Chagos','+06','06:00:00','false'
'Asia/Rangoon','+0630','06:30:00','false'
'Asia/Yangon','+0630','06:30:00','false'
'Indian/Cocos','+0630','06:30:00','false'
'Antarctica/Davis','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Bangkok','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Barnaul','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Hovd','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Jakarta','WIB','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Krasnoyarsk','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Novokuznetsk','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Novosibirsk','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Phnom_Penh','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Pontianak','WIB','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Saigon','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Tomsk','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Asia/Vientiane','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-7','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Indian/Christmas','+07','07:00:00','false'
'Antarctica/Casey','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Brunei','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Choibalsan','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Chongqing','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Chungking','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Harbin','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Hong_Kong','HKT','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Irkutsk','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Kuching','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Macao','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Macau','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Makassar','WITA','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Manila','PST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Shanghai','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Singapore','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Taipei','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ujung_Pandang','WITA','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ulaanbaatar','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ulan_Bator','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Australia/Perth','AWST','08:00:00','false'
'Australia/West','AWST','08:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-8','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Hongkong','HKT','08:00:00','false'
'PRC','CST','08:00:00','false'
'ROC','CST','08:00:00','false'
'Singapore','+08','08:00:00','false'
'Australia/Eucla','+0845','08:45:00','false'
'Asia/Chita','+09','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Dili','+09','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Jayapura','WIT','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Khandyga','+09','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Pyongyang','KST','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Seoul','KST','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Tokyo','JST','09:00:00','false'
'Asia/Yakutsk','+09','09:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-9','+09','09:00:00','false'
'Japan','JST','09:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Palau','+09','09:00:00','false'
'ROK','KST','09:00:00','false'
'Australia/Adelaide','ACST','09:30:00','false'
'Australia/Broken_Hill','ACST','09:30:00','false'
'Australia/Darwin','ACST','09:30:00','false'
'Australia/North','ACST','09:30:00','false'
'Australia/South','ACST','09:30:00','false'
'Australia/Yancowinna','ACST','09:30:00','false'
'Antarctica/DumontDUrville','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Asia/Ust-Nera','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Asia/Vladivostok','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/ACT','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Brisbane','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Canberra','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Currie','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Hobart','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Lindeman','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Melbourne','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/NSW','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Queensland','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Sydney','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Tasmania','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/Victoria','AEST','10:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-10','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Chuuk','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Guam','ChST','10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Port_Moresby','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Saipan','ChST','10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Truk','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Yap','+10','10:00:00','false'
'Australia/LHI','+1030','10:30:00','false'
'Australia/Lord_Howe','+1030','10:30:00','false'
'Antarctica/Macquarie','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Asia/Magadan','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Asia/Sakhalin','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Asia/Srednekolymsk','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-11','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Bougainville','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Efate','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Guadalcanal','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Kosrae','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Norfolk','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Noumea','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Pohnpei','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Ponape','+11','11:00:00','false'
'Antarctica/McMurdo','NZST','12:00:00','false'
'Antarctica/South_Pole','NZST','12:00:00','false'
'Asia/Anadyr','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Asia/Kamchatka','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-12','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Kwajalein','+12','12:00:00','false'
'NZ','NZST','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Auckland','NZST','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Fiji','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Funafuti','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Kwajalein','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Majuro','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Nauru','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Tarawa','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Wake','+12','12:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Wallis','+12','12:00:00','false'
'NZ-CHAT','+1245','12:45:00','false'
'Pacific/Chatham','+1245','12:45:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-13','+13','13:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Apia','+13','13:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Enderbury','+13','13:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Fakaofo','+13','13:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Tongatapu','+13','13:00:00','false'
'Etc/GMT-14','+14','14:00:00','false'
'Pacific/Kiritimati','+14','14:00:00','false'
```