# Getting the list of timezones supported by PostgreSQL in Django using RawSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to get the list of all the timezones supported by PSQL database in my Django project, so I can validate timestamps with timezones before sending them to the the database. I asked another question and got an answer regarding the PSQL query here:

[How to get the list of timezones supported by PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000372/how-to-get-the-list-of-timezones-supported-by-postgresql/)

Using that, I am trying to do the following:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

RawSQL("SELECT name, abbrev, utc_offset, is_dst FROM pg_timezone_names;", [])
```

However, it does not seem to work. I saw the docs for `RawSQL`, and it usually has a model attached to it, which I can't really have. How to do solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work for you

```
from django.db import connection

 with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, abbrev, utc_offset, is_dst FROM pg_timezone_names")
    zones = cursor.fetchall()
```